# Displaying images in Thumbnail Image Gallery 

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

Here I am trying to create an Image Gallery: http://jsfiddle.net/5wETg/62/.

```
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel> <image>http://www.nikon.com/swf/img/thumbnail_ophthalmic_lenses.png</image> <image>http://www.nikon.com/swf/img/thumbnail_ophthalmic_lenses.png</image> <image>http://www.nikon.com/swf/img/thumbnail_ophthalmic_lenses.png</image> <limage>http://images1.videolan.org/images/largeVLC.png</limage> <limage>http://images1.videolan.org/images/largeVLC.png</limage> <limage>http://images1.videolan.org/images/largeVLC.png</limage>   </channel></rss>",

xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$image= $xml.find( "image" );
$limage = $xml.find("limage");

$( "#thumbs" ).append( $image.map(function(){
        return $('<img>', {className: 'thumbnails', src:$(this).text()})[0];
    })

        $( "#panel" ).append( $image.map(function(){
        return $('<img>', {className: 'largeimages', src:$(this).text()})[0];
    })
);
```

I have to show both the thumbnail images and larger images, but there is problem images are not getting displayed. I need some help.

Comment: `there is problem in showing the images` what do you mean? images not getting displayed?

Comment: @blasteralfred: Images are not getting displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

- The first `append()` is not being closed correctly (you're missing the closing `)`);
- You are using the `image` array instead of `limage` for the larger images.

Here's a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L7yKp/)**.

Comment: Thanks I understand I forgot to use limage. minor issue. Thanks alot